# PHP, merge two arrays: first array values become keys in the merged array

Tags: php, arrays, merge

I have two arrays

```
[0] => 40
[1] => 41
[2] => 42
[3] => 43
[4] => 44
```

and

```
[0] => 2
[1] => 2
[2] => 2
[3] => 1
[4] => 0
```

The first array rappresents the sizes of a product and the second the quantities.
I want to create an associative array where each size is the key and the quantity is the value.

The arrays above will become this

```
[40] => 2
[41] => 2
[42] => 2
[43] => 1
[44] => 0
```

Is there a quick way of doing it ? I have 5000+ records and I have to do it for each one of them.

In the end it will become a string like `40-2;41-2;43-2;44-1;45-0`

Thank you.

Comment: `$arr1 = array(40, 41, 42, 43, 44);
  $arr2 = array(2, 2, 2, 1, 0);

  $array = array_combine($arr1, $arr2);
  print_r($array);` As simple as that

Comment: @Rizier123 Thanks, I didn't know about array_combine.